# Python to perform SSH logins and do something

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, netapp

I am trying to automate few routine tasks in Netapp storage using Python.

Since I am using Windows machine and Python  I need to perform few tasks to connect storage using ssh session and perfom few things and I need view how it is acting . For example if we take we are connecting  Linux box  over ssh if I execute ls command I need to see the output of the ls.

To achieve this which tools I need to use ..I searched in web some are suggesting to use paramiko and pexpect but these  are the modules to use connect ssh and perform tasks but we cannot view the output on terminal.

Comment: There is an experimental reduced-functionality pexpect for windows but not very useful if you need interact with the child process. If you use paramiko, you could print everything you receive and send for viewing, or use the `logging` module to log it.

Answer (score 1):

With the parallel-ssh library:

```
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
# See also private key examples in documentation
client = ParallelSSHClient(['netapp.host'], user=<user>,
                           password=<password>)
output = client.run_command(<cmd>)
for line in output['netapp.host'].stdout:
    print line
```

See [parallel-ssh](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) documentation. It uses paramiko under the hood so should work just as well on Windows.

`stdin` channel is also available in output for providing input like with pexpect, [see run_command documentation](http://parallel-ssh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pssh_client.html#pssh.pssh_client.ParallelSSHClient.run_command) for examples.

As a bonus, the client is parallel and can be used to run commands on any number of hosts.

Using paramiko directly is of course also possible, though a lot more code would be required which parallel-ssh does for you.

Comment: It will establish many channels or one Chanel? If I execute many commands continuously

Comment: One persistent connection per host, new SSH channel per call to `run_command`. Can run multiple commands in a single channel by using multiple shell commands, eg `uname; whoami` etc. (requires use of a shell to state the obvious).